# How do I get a cert from a pfx

Tags: android, https, x509certficiate2

I'm developing an android app for a client (this is the first time I do this) and I need to entablish a secured connection, they gave me a pfx file but I have no password nor any data about this cert, I'm totally new to certificates and https connections, what I need to know is if just the pfx is enough to ensure the app can connect by https or do I need to ask anything else to my client, I know I need to get a cert file to import it in the app, but I don't have the password for this pfx file. Sorry for my bad english though.

Just to make it clear, I'm not asking for the implementation of the certificate itself, I just need to know what do I need to start the implementation (files, information about the certificate, etc).